# Scripts that checks for approximately equal string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a system where users can create their own pesonal recipes with corresponding ingredients and save them (in mysql).

The problem is that every time an ingredient is saved i check if it allready exists in the ingredients table where i compare the names of the ingredients.

If i should be able to make properly shopping lists from the recipes i want to make sure that for example:

apple - apples - fresh apples
Cant apear

So if "apple" first is created and im trying to save "apples" i wanna check something similar allready exists.

Does an alghorithm like what im trying to explain allready exists?

Hope you have some input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to use [soundex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) or [Levenshtein distance](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552), it would still require finding the key word in the phrase - with 'apple' and 'apples' it would probably work, but with 'dozen of fresh apples' - probably not.

From my experience, in that application nothing beats more manual algorithms:

- create a base list of ingredients ("flour", "apple", "ham")
- when adding new recipe, match ingredient list against the the list, possibly allowing for some fuzzyness using Levenshtein or regexes
- create a backend page with a list of "original" vs "match", with a possibly to mark wrong matches with a single click
- create a simple interface to do a manual matching for bad hits

Comment: Im gonna check that Levenshtein out. And i think i'm gonna make a backend system like you are talking about where i can mark those wrong matches.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with MySQL's `SOUNDEX()` function, assuming that the words are similar enough and, probably, simple enough.

Documentation can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Basically, what it does is reduce a given word to a four character string representing it. The string should be the same for any two words that *sound* largely the same.

Comment: I'm going to check that out immediately

Comment: Just updated the answer with a little more detail... I hope it helps!

Comment: I think that function can solve my ploblem for now. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

In mySql you can use `SOUNDEX()` function [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

If you want to implement it in php there is [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) and [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) functions